How to change Airflow docker image?
I got working Airflow image.
But I need add new Python library to Airflow.
I got "/opt/beget/airflow/docker-compose.yml".

I create file Dockerfile in same folder with code:
FROM apache/airflow
RUN pip install clickhouse-connect

So I need edit current image apache/airflow.
there's my images (docker images):

All I need to edit current Airflow image.
P.S. I using:

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-107-generic x86_64)
Docker version 26.1.3, build b72abbb


Here is an example. Let's say you have a docker-compose.yml(I skipped scheduler, celery etc - only webserver):
version: '3.7'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: apache/airflow:2.8.2
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: LocalExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
  depends_on:
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: airflow_postgres
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
      - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow" ]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: version
    container_name: airflow_init
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_MIGRATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: airflow
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: airflow

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    container_name: airflow_webserver
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - airflow-init

Let's run containers: docker-compose up -d and wait until the webserver is healthy. You can call curl http://localhost:8080/login/ or just use a browser.

Now let's build our custom image, Dockerfile:
FROM apache/airflow:2.8.2
RUN pip install clickhouse-connect==0.7.19

Run docker build -t my_custom_airflow:1.0 .
Our custom image is ready. Now we need to replace airflow container

docker-compose stop airflow-webserver
docker-compose rm -f airflow-init airflow-webserver

# replace `image: apache/airflow:2.8.2` to `image: my_custom_airflow:1.0` in docker-compose.yml
# run new containers and wait until they are healthy
docker-compose up -d


Let's check:
# containers
docker ps
# CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                                       NAMES
# 9e51c50dc0f2   my_custom_airflow:1.0   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   4 minutes ago    Up 4 minutes (healthy)    0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   airflow_webserver
# cdd095406be9   postgres:13             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   20 minutes ago   Up 20 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   airflow_postgres

# our python package
docker-compose exec airflow-webserver bash -c "pip freeze" | grep clickhouse
# clickhouse-connect==0.7.19

